# Eclipse Ant JDK issue

Tags: eclipse, ant, java

I have given atask to buld the ant file.
The interestuing path is there is no JDK installed, only JVM is installed.
It seems to me that Eclipse is using internally JDK.

Now, when I run the ant file it's throwing me an exception  Unable to find a javac compiler; so how Can I fix this ?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the current Eclipse help: [Using the ant javac adapter](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-ant_javac_adapter.htm)

> The Eclipse compiler can be used inside an Ant buildfile using the javac adapter. In order to use the Eclipse compiler, you simply need to define the build.compiler property in your buildfile.

This might also work in Eclipse 3.4.  Ganymede help files aren't online.

Edited to add the ant compiler property definition:

```
 <property name="build.compiler" 
    value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
```

Comment: How to find which JDK is using by Eclipse? In in the Eclipse IDE inside Installed JRE i can see value as JRE 6, but not able to find JDK. In my system Oracle is installed too. It has javac.exe..My question how to make sure which JDK it using?

Comment: @yser900721: You specify the location of the JRE in your Ant script.  See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse JDT (Java developement tool) is able to run on top of a JRE only as you said because it embed its own Java compiler. I think you can use this compiler to compile code outside Eclipse but I am not able yet to find ressources on the web explaining how to do this.

Moreover I am not sure you will be able to tell Ant (here I speak about Ant running outside Eclipse, because Eclipse also has its own internal Ant runner) to use this compiler instead of using the javac compiler find in default location.

Comment: Yes, ANT is inside the eclipse only. I have not done anything to install ant.so there should be something to run ANT.

Comment: If you are running ant inside eclipse you don't need anything. Can you please edit your question in order to tell us How exactly you are running ANT and put the full ant error output. Thanks.

Comment: <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" />                    When I use above line in ant file, it says no Java compiler found. How to resolve this.